# Protect Python script with Google Drive (perhaps Google App Engine)

Tags: python, security, exe, google-drive-api

I have trouble with understanding if it's possible to protect a python script from stealing it (I know this is not in fact possible but at least let's protect it as much as possible) **by uploading the program made in python to Google Drive**. I did reasearch such as How do I protect my python code? or [Store Python scripts & run them online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904977/somewhere-to-store-python-scripts-run-them-online) and many more or less relevant links. But none of them is really answering me.

Let's say **I have a python project made a Windows Executable (.exe) with GUI2Exe**. It has GUI which **loads images from specific folders** etc.

**I upload all of that to Google Drive.**

**Somehow run that program** from Google Drive and if you can make the user not to realise it that it is from Google Drive than it is even better (log in interface etc)

I would like to know **if one of the next solutions are possible** or there is another way:

- run the exe directly from Google Drive (oh, naivity, or perhaps there is something there I don't see)
- run the exe from Google Drive with the help of another python code which can be on your computer but does nothing more than log in to Google and Run the exe from the right folder or download it to temporary and run it from there automatically.
- using Google Drive as Windows Service so I guess you can use it as a simple partition of your computer and run the program from there [Here is a better description](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunGoogleDriveAsAService.html)
- perhaps avoiding Google as it is and use some kind of encrypting (though I understood it's not really for python)

Becuase my python program has already more then 20000 lines of code and uses about 20 python libraries and needs to load formats as jpg, png, csv (spreadsheets) (etc.) I don't think that Google App Engine is enough. Though I'm quite a noob here so I can be very very wrong.

I hope I made myself clear and **please just give me a lead** if you can. The right way to go about this and I do my homework. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider renting an EC2 Windows instance. Set it up with all the libraries you'll require.